# How to get UTF-16 numeric value of a characters in python?

Tags: python

My goal is something like this

Input:

> "ABC"

Output:

> [0x0041, 0x0042, 0x0043]

The outputs are corrosponding UTF-16 value of each character. How do I get the numeric(BIN/HEX/DEC) UTF-16 value from a string or single character?

Comment: What you claim to what for output looks more like the hexadecimal literals for the Unicode codepoints than the UTF-16 encoding for each character.

Comment: Yes. That is what I need some way to get that value.

Comment: If you wanted UTF-16: `'ABC'.encode('utf-16')`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Python 3, you can do that as follows:

```py
for i in "ABC":
    print(hex(ord(i)))
```

> 0x41 0x42 0x43

Comment: Depending on python build, this may give you unicode codepoints rather than UTF-16 codepoints; whether this matters to the OP (or has non-BMP characters) is up to them.

Comment: @Max good note, thank you.

Comment: @Max What build do you think *wouldn't* produce Unicode code points?

Comment: @Max With this I can find my way to my goal. It felt like there should be an obvious easy way to get corrosponding numeric UTF-16(or other encoding)  value from character but this will do.

Comment: @chepner I’m not sure of my history exactly, but Python <= 3.2 Narrow builds.  Probably obsolete enough not to worry about now.

Comment: Yikes, yeah, that's extremely obsolete.